# <type 'exceptions.IOError'>: [Errno 13] Permission denied using cElementTree on appengine

Tags: python, xml, google-app-engine

Trying to grab an xml file from an internet source and parse it for some values.
My code:

```
def get_xml(self):

    #xml_url =   "http://www.shoppingcar.it/feed/export_vel.asp?parametro=1"
    xml_url =   "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/102727/AutoVeloce%20XML%20Splitter/shoppingcar.xml"

    MAX_RETRY = 3
    retry_left = MAX_RETRY

    while retry_left:
        try:
            req =   urlfetch.fetch(xml_url, deadline=10)
            XML =   req.content.decode('windows-1252')
            break   # <- done! got file.

        except (urllib2.HTTPError, DownloadError):
            retry_left -= 1
            logging.error("Error while downloading ShoppingCar.xml, retrying.")
        except DeadlineExceededError:
            retry_left -= 1
            logging.warning("DeadlineExceededError while downloading ShoppingCar.xml, retrying.")
        except Timeout:
            retry_left -= 1
            logging.warning("Timeout while downloading ShoppingCar.xml, retrying.")

    if retry_left and retry_left < MAX_RETRY:
        logging.info("Downloading ShoppingCar.xml succeeded after %s retries.", MAX_RETRY - retry_left)
    if not retry_left:
        logging.error("Downloading ShoppingCar.xml failed after %s retries.", MAX_RETRY)

    return ET.parse(XML)

def _iter_carDicts_in_xml(self, newOnly=True):

    #fails here >
    tree = self.get_xml()

    for veicolo in tree.getiterator('veicolo'):
        # do stuff
```

Error message I get:

```
<type 'exceptions.IOError'>: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?><veicoli>\r\n    <veicolo>\r\n\t\t<id><![CDATA[26806]]></id>
```

This error continues spitting out the xml file so i won't paste it all

Really not sure where to go on this one, I've used similar code to extract from xml files and never had this kind of problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parse` function expects file object. Try `parse(StringIO(XML))` instead.

Comment: this did indeed get me past the IOError, thank you.

However, now I have `<type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>: no element found: line 1, column 0` but I will assume this is a separate error and mark yours as correct. thanks again.

Comment: the code i added looks like this: `import StringIO`, `XMLio = StringIO.StringIO(XML)`, `return ET.parse(XMLio)`

Comment: OK I figured it all out. You should normally be able to do `ET.parse(urllib.urlopen('url'))`, problem was that GAE's `urlfetch` wasn't returning what ET was looking for (I don't know the details). All I know is that `ET.parse(urllib.urlopen('url'))` DOES work just fine and I was able to download and parse the xml file with just that line.

Answer (score -1):

You may not be authorized to use this link (i.e. to make a request on this link).

Comment: I have tried the original link given to me, as well as a copy I downloaded and stuck into a public dropbox folder. Both are accessible by regular browsers.